Create a file with an OLE 1.0 Embedded Object
I need to create a file (doc, spreadsheet or otherwise) which has an OLE 1.0 embedded object in it. The object must be embedded using the OLE 1.0 standard.
This is a very old Microsoft standard for embedding objects within office files (.doc, .xls etc.)
I'm having trouble finding any way to create such a file. Does anyone know how I could do this?

TBH if you just need some kind of test file, the simplest way is probably to create a VM that runs a suitably old version of Windows+Word+Excel and create the .doc or .xls manually.

That would be a version produced from 1990, when OLE 1.0 was released, to 1993, when OLE 2.0 was released.

You might be able to use https://www.pcjs.org/ to do it rather than creating your own VM etc.

Just looking around this problem, you may be able to do this even with a modern version of Word, by using Insert->Object and choosing an application that still only implements OLE1. e.g.on Win10 that may be possible by embedding a Paint object. The difficulty is working out exactly what object type has been embedded...

...AFAICS by saving as RTF and inspecting the object's binary code, it doesn't have a compound file (OLE2) signature but it does look more like the OLE1 format described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oleds/b6eebcf1-99d0-4a43-b532-f326a4ec09b4 (although the description seems to me to lack clarity and is possibly wrong about some of the "field" lengths. But I really cannot tell.
